# Google Analytics SDK 3.0 _sqlite3 linker errors in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, google-analytics

I'm integrating **Google Analytics SDK 3.0** in my project. But I am getting **linker errors** when try to build my project.

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/#headers), I have linked following libraries in my project,

- *libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a*
- *AdSupport.framework*
- *CoreData.framework*
- *SystemConfiguration.framework*
- *libz.dylib*

Even then, I get following errors on building the project,

```
d: warning: directory not found for option '-L"/Users/....NameProject/Libraries/Google Analytics"'
"_sqlite3_bind_blob", referenced from:
  -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl writeEntriesToDatabase:expireTime:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
"_sqlite3_bind_int", referenced from:
  -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl deleteEntries:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
"_sqlite3_bind_int64", referenced from:
  -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl writeEntriesToDatabase:expireTime:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)
  -[TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl peekEntryIds:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataLayerPersistentStoreImpl.o)

....
```

What is causing these errors? Am I missing anything?

Appreciate your help.

---

**SOLUTION:**

I solved it by linking my project with `libsqlite3.0` library. The Google analytics documentation missed out mentioning to link this library. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for sharing ! You may consider answering your own question.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing this answer. It must have something to do with Google's latest Analytics library. Jesus Google update your docs when changing something!

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You can solve this issue importing "**libsqlite3.0**"

Comment: Why Google did not ask to add "libsqlite3.0"?

Comment: Works like a charm, Thank you.